# Pandas merge: MemoryError:

Tags: python, pandas

I got a memory problem with pandas. 
I've been searching around but I cant find a solution that works for me. 
I belive this is a PEBCAK error since im new to python and pandas.

this is the code that causes the error:

```
filelist = glob.glob("./data/*.csv")
df = pd.DataFrame()

for i in filelist:
    tmp = pd.read_csv(i)
    ticker = i.split('/')[-1].split('.')[0].replace('data\\','')
    data = pd.DataFrame(tmp, columns=["close", "closePct","date"])
    data = data.rename(columns={'close': ticker, 'closePct': ticker+"Pct"})

    # get only stocks with 10y of data
    if len(data) > (250*10):
        if len(df.columns) > 0:
            df = pd.merge(df, data, on='date')
            df = df.dropna()            
        else:
            df = data.copy()

        print(len(df.columns))
    else: 
        print("drop " + ticker)


df.set_index('date', inplace=True)
```

The number of files im trying to read are around 200 and they contain 2500 rows each. I want to only pick the columns date, close and closePct. I rename the columns to the ticker namn to keep track for the stocks.

I've tried using dask but that didnt work so well. :S

Br

Comment: Is `merge` the right method in this case? This looks like an `append`.

Comment: Can you confirm `merge` works as expected? I am suspecting that something fishy is happening doing inner join that blows your dataframe.

Comment: @eduffy I dont want to append. I want every new stock to be added as a new column with the headers (for example) AAPL AAPLPct, (i.e price and percentage for cose)

Comment: @LukaszTracewski when I printed df.head() for every merge it looks ok. I will try when im at home to inspect the whole dataframe after merge to controll it works as expected. Because the result i see when printing head() looks ok.

Comment: @LukaszTracewski I've checked the dataframe and it looks correct after each merge. Any other suggestion?